# NPM doesn't work properly with scoped modules from git repos

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm still waiting for the company set up its account on NPM to allow me to use private modules.

Meanwhile, I'm making it work with npm + git private repos.

In order to reduce the friction when we finally switch to NPM private modules, I was willing to declare dependencies like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@company/repo": "git+https://<token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/company/repo"
  }
}
```

And then, in my code, do this:

```
import repo from '@company/repo'
```

However, when I run `npm install`and inspect my `node_modules/`, instead of finding something like:

```
node_modules
├── @company
│   └── repo
├── ...
```

The resulting structure is flat, there is no `@company` folder:

```
node_modules
├── repo
├── ...
```

I couldn't find anything in the NPM docs about this behavior with git repos, so I want to know if this is a possible bug or if it's working as designed.